# Word VBA "Find" does not start from start position, but before it

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word Find - Replace VBA Macro that I call from Excel that runs correctly in normal cases, which is like below :

```
Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\............")
Set myRange = wordDoc.Range

Do
    With myRange.Find
        lookUp = "\<\<*\>\>"
        If .Execute(Forward:=True, MatchWildcards:=True, MatchWholeWord:=False, FindText:=lookUp) Then

        foundText = myRange.Text
        posEnd = myRange.End

       .Execute Forward:=True, MatchWildcards:=False, MatchWholeWord:=True, 
        FindText:=foundText, ReplaceWith:="Some text...", Replace:=2

    Set myRange = wordDoc.Range(posEnd, wordDoc.Range.End)

    Else
        Exit Do
    End with
Loop
```

This code works fine. The strange behavior happens when 2 same values are found consecutively.

On the below line, I set the start position of the range :

```
Set myRange = wordDoc.Range(posEnd, wordDoc.Range.End)
```

After this line I debugged myRange variable and saw that its start position is let's say 360, after the loop goes to do again and the next find, it finds a match but the myrange start value is 342 and it finds exactly the same value over and over.

I know there is an option to do `While .find = true`, but I don't understand what is wrong with this approach, why Word VBA finds a value before the range's Start position?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find) "*If you've gotten to the Find object from the Range object, the selection isn't changed when text matching the find criteria is found, but the Range object is redefined.*" so between giving the variable "posEnd" and the line with SetRange, `myRange` has already been redefined? I couldn't figure out right away how you're doing this from Excel so I didn't get to test it out but maybe give it a look.

Comment: @Notus_Panda I edited the question to show how actually I set the range. After the first find myRange becomes the found value's range where Start = 340 and End is 362. After replace, I define myRange as start = found value's end (362)  and End = End of document position (5500). The loop makes another find and next found value (myRange) start = 342 and end = 362. The problem is how the found value's start can be 342 while the search range starts from 362.

Comment: Using `.Find.Wrap = wdFindStop` to stop the find when it reach the end of doc.

Comment: @taller I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: This doesn't explain the problem because right now I can't see how the "second" start can be anything less than 362, but there is another problem you may need to fix: if your first find Range is 340 to 362 and the replacement text is only 10 characters long then you should start the next search at around 350, otherwise you'll miss a piece of text, or if the substitutions mean the doc is actually less than 362 characters wrong you will get an error in your Set myRange statement in the loop. And (less likely!) a *longer* replacement text that contained the search text might loop indefinitely.

Comment: NB I'm assuming that there is a typo in the code you posted and that you are actually doing Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open... at the top. Probably not relevant.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, corrected now

Comment: Try Set myRange = wordDoc.Range(posEnd+1, wordDoc.Range.End).  The +1 moves you out of the previously found range.

Comment: @jonsson you are right, the substituted text is longer than the original text and I should set the beginning range accordingly. if you can write it as answer I will mark it, thank you

Comment: Has that definitely solved the problem, though?

Comment: No, actually it didn't, I applied the While .find = true method which resolved the issue